# Mobile application real-time voice stream to multiple clients

Tags: android, ios, mobile

My application should stream voice from one device to all the other devices on the network (similar to PTT. only 1 device steams to the other devices)
Assumptions:
1. The speaker can be either Android or iPhone.
2. The network does not support multicast.
3. All the devices are connected a local router (no internet in the environment).
4. The maximum amount of devices is 40.

How should I implement this feature? Is there an open-source SDK for this? Is there a non-free SKD for this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe WebRTC can solve your problem. Check it out https://webrtc.org/

Comment: Can i send using webrtc audio to 40 subscribers without a server?

Comment: Actually, you need a signaling and sure you can get more than 40 subscribers. Signaling is the process of coordinating communication. In order for a WebRTC application to set up a 'call', its clients need to exchange information.
You can use XMPP, socket io or Pubnub etc, anything can help you transfer message real time, to help to transfer your message call and you can use free STUN server provided by Google.
You can read more about WebRTC there https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/ .

Answer (score 0):

Tokbox

yes, here's the best one out there that i've used extensively, not only for audio chat but also video and more, it works perfectly with IOS if you know what you're doing

https://tokbox.com

Comment: Does it support serverless communication? i need 1 device to stream the voice to the other devices without a server

Comment: no, because serverless communication is a violation of multiple international laws, are you a terrorist?

Comment: no. i just want to stream audio on local wifi without internet connection